# How can I style a select box to look like this: https://postimg.cc/image/tm5jzc6g7/

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to style the  using css, but I can't figure out how to make it look like the select box in the [link above](https://postimg.cc/image/tm5jzc6g7/), but css wont let me change the background color of the options. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an active class with the styles you want

eg

```
.current {
     color: green;
     .icon { 
         opacity: 1;
     }
}
```

and then add this class or remove this class based on the current one clicked

```
const newest = document.querySelector('newestElt')
newest.addEventListener('click', () => {  
   removeClass();
   newest.classList.add('current');
}

function removeClass() {
    const navItems = document.getElementsByClassName('navItems');
    var navArray = [].slice.call(navItems);
    navArray.forEach(item => {
        document.querySelector('a').classList.remove('current');
    });
}
```

There is probably a cleaner and shorter solution but this will work